# OpenCV Multi-Threaded Thread Message

Tags: .net, c++, multithreading, opencv, message-passing

I am writing a program using .Net 3.5 and **OpenCV 1.1**. I have multiple threads that need to get an image variables from the web camera on my computer, the problem being I get memory violation errors when multiple threads try to access the camera at the same time. I know I can use PostThreadMessage and GetMessage to send a variable to the threads. Can anyone give me a tutorial or example of how to pass a variable to a thread while it is running using `PostThreadMessage` and `GetMessage`?

The errors I get are memory access violation errors, when both of my worker threads try to call a function that gets an image from the camera. I want to get around this by having one thread get the images for all of the others. They each have their one **IplImage** variable that stores the image captured by the camera. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you want to copy the camera image in a serial fashion, then operate on the copied data (the IplImage) in a multi-threaded way.

To safely do this, as the unknown guy pointed out, you have to lock the memory (or variable(s)) you're potentially accessing with your threads. A very short example of how to do this with a Windows [CRITICAL_SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28VS.85%29.aspx) is as follows:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

/* Initialize the critical section -- This must be done before locking */
InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);

...

/* Release system object when all finished -- 
usually at the end of the cleanup code */
DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
```

Now when you're accessing the camera (or any un-sharable resource for that matter) you simply surround the thing you're accessing with the following two lines:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

/* Operate on your shared data */

LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

Surrounding your code (e.g. IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(xyz);) with these two lines should fix your collisions.. but it sounds like your code could do with a little more organization..

Answer (score 0):

Where are the memory errors occurring? Can you post some more detail? Are they occurring during accesses to your data structures, or to OpenCV ones? If it's the latter, then I am not sure how messaging is going to help. In either case, a little bit of locking around non-thread-safe data structures sounds like enough.